Supabase invite user, but change his provider from email to facebook / google / apple?
I have a form in dashboard where you can invite a user to be a teacher or admin. The way I do this is through a form, and a server action:
"use server"

interface InvitationParams {
  email: string;
  role: string;
}

export async function inviteTeacherOrAdmin(params: InvitationParams) {
  try {
    const { email, role } = params;

    const { data, error } = await supabaseAdmin.auth.admin.inviteUserByEmail(
      email,
      //password_signin is misleading, It's actually only oauth.(workin on it)

      { data: { role: role },
redirectTo: 'http://localhost:3000/signin/password_signin' },
    );

    if (error) console.log('Error:', error);

    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw error;
  }
}

I am trying to get these 2 types of users through a different way, unlike normal users.
So normally, when a user signs in for the first time, there's a trigger function that creates a new row in a public.users table. This row will contain id, full_name, email, avatar.
These fields will be populated because I only use Google and Facebook auth. (Later I will set up Apple too).
Then after completing a form, inside users.role the value "student" will be added.
The trigger function:
begin
    insert into public.users (id, full_name, avatar_url, email)
    values (new.id, new.raw_user_meta_data->>'full_name', new.raw_user_meta_data->>'avatar_url', new.raw_user_meta_data->>'email');
    return new;
end;

security - Definer
Problem:
When I send the invite, a user is created, but the provider is 'email', which triggers the function and in public.users I only get an ID, but full_name: null, avatar:null role:null. The invited user logs in, which triggers errors because they are null. So when testing this, I have to log in, log out or refresh the page, and then I get the values. And the user metadata will have both email and google/facebook as providers. Not cool. How do I solve it?
